# Why does Pytorch claim my input has 4 channels?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I was trying to train an SRGAN-model on my dataset of text images. Those are 100 160x30 .png files.

Here is the model:
https://github.com/leftthomas/SRGAN/blob/master/model.py
https://github.com/leftthomas/SRGAN/blob/master/train.py
(I didn't change anything apart from the path to my dataset)

I set the crop_size to 24, the upscale to 2 and start the training, but then the following error occurs:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 9, 9], expected input[64, 4, 12, 12] to have 3 channels, but got 4 channels instead
```

I am sure that all of my images have 3 channels, which is confirmed by `img.shape`.

Nevertheless, I am stuck and, honestly, I have no idea where exactly this fourth channel might be.

Comment: PyTorch mostly requires your input to be 4-D, [batch_size, num_of_channels, length, width]. So, check whether you are transforming your input into the correct dimensions. Number of channels is 3 for RGB images, 1 for grayscale images and so on.

Comment: Could you put your `DataLoader` code here? I think that is where the problem is.